# Center a Row of Data in a Table so that Data is Aligned at the Center Column

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

Good Afternoon,

I could use a hand.  Ultimately what I would like to do is generate a table where each row of data is populated so that it’s centered at a specific column, and the determining factor of where to center the row of data is an attribute “tag=0”.

Also there is something I should make clear is that the number of seats in a row will vary and the number of seats either side of Center Line will vary. Unlimited variations other than there will always be at least one seat with the attribute “tag=0”.

Here is the xml file of the source data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="seatarrangement_testbed.xsl"?>
<hall>
    <row name="a">
        <seat tag="-3">-3_seat_A1</seat>
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_A2</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_A3</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_A4</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_A5</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_A6</seat>
        <seat tag="3">+4_seat_A7</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="b">
        <seat tag="-4">-4_seat_B1</seat>
        <seat tag="-3">-3_seat_B2</seat>
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_B3</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_B4</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_B5</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_B6</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_B7</seat>
        <seat tag="3">+4_seat_B8</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="c">
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_C1</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_C2</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_C3</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_C4</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_C5</seat>
        <seat tag="3">+3_seat_C6</seat>
        <seat tag="4">+4_seat_C7</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="d">
        <seat tag="-5">-5_seat_D1</seat>
        <seat tag="-4">-4_seat_D2</seat>
        <seat tag="-3">-3_seat_D3</seat>
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_D4</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_D5</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_D6</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_D7</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_D8</seat>
        <seat tag="3">+4_seat_D9</seat>
        <seat tag="4">+5_seat_D10</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="e">
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_E1</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_E2</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_E3</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_E4</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_E5</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="f">
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_E1</seat>
        <seat tag="1">+2_seat_E2</seat>
        <seat tag="2">+3_seat_E3</seat>
        <seat tag="3">+4_seat_E4</seat>
        <seat tag="4">+5_seat_E5</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="g">
        <seat tag="-4">-4_seat_E1</seat>
        <seat tag="-3">-3_seat_E2</seat>
        <seat tag="-2">-2_seat_E3</seat>
        <seat tag="-1">-1_seat_E4</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_E5</seat>
    </row>
</hall>
```

My approach may not be the best, but what I was pursuing was to find the number of previous sibling ‘seat’ in each ‘row’, from the sibling with the attribute “tag=0”.  Then find what is the largest value these counted siblings of each row and use that to shift the data accordingly.

This is the end result I was looking for:

[image]

And this is the manually created html file of the desired result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Seating_Arrangement_testbed</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Seating Arrangement</h2>
      <table summary="greatest position of CL" border="1">
         <tr align="center">
            <th></th>
            <th><b>5th Left Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>4th Left Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>3th Left Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>2th Left Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>1th Left Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>1th Right Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>2th Right Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>3th Right Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>4th Right Lane</b></th>
            <th><b>5th Right Lane</b></th>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
               <td></td>
              <td>-3_seat_A1</td>
            <td>-2_seat_A2</td>
            <td>-1_seat_A3</td>
            <td>+1_seat_A4</td>
            <td>+2_seat_A5</td>
            <td>+3_seat_A6</td>
            <td>+4_seat_A7</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
               <td>-4_seat_B1</td>
            <td>-3_seat_B2</td>
            <td>-2_seat_B3</td>
            <td>-1_seat_B4</td>
            <td>+1_seat_B5</td>
            <td>+2_seat_B6</td>
            <td>+3_seat_B7</td>
            <td>+4_seat_B8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>-2_seat_C1</td>
            <td>-1_seat_C2</td>
            <td>+1_seat_C3</td>
            <td>+2_seat_C4</td>
            <td>+3_seat_C5</td>
            <td>+4_seat_C6</td>
            <td>+5_seat_C7</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>d</td>
               <td>-5_seat_D1</td>
            <td>-4_seat_D2</td>
            <td>-3_seat_D3</td>
            <td>-2_seat_D4</td>
            <td>-1_seat_D5</td>
            <td>+1_seat_D6</td>
            <td>+2_seat_D7</td>
            <td>+3_seat_D8</td>
            <td>+4_seat_D9</td>
            <td>+5_seat_D10</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>e</td>
            <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td>-2_seat_E1</td>
            <td>-1_seat_E2</td>
            <td>+1_seat_E3</td>
            <td>+2_seat_E4</td>
            <td>+3_seat_E5</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>f</td>
            <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td><td>+1_seat_E1</td>
            <td>+2_seat_E2</td>
            <td>+3_seat_E3</td>
            <td>+4_seat_E4</td>
            <td>+5_seat_E5</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="right">
            <td>g</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>-4_seat_E1</td>
            <td>-3_seat_E2</td>
            <td>-2_seat_E3</td>
            <td>-1_seat_E4</td>
            <td>+1_seat_E5</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>7</tr>
         <tr>46</tr>
         <tr>5</tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is the xsl stylesheet that I have come up with so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--XSLT 1.0 - http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training -->
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">

    <xsl:variable name="STAtotal" select="count(/hall/row)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Seattotal" select="count(/hall/row/seat)"/>

    <!--Attempt_2
        <xsl:for-each select="/hall/row/seat[@tag='0']">
        <xsl:sort select="count(preceding-sibling::seat[@tag='0'])" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:variable name="OSLeft" select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    Attempt_2-->

    <head>
        <title>Seating_Arrangement_testbed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Seating Arrangement</h2>


        <table summary="greatest position of CL" border="1">

            <tr align="center">
                <th/>
                <th>
                    <b>5th Left Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>4th Left Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>3th Left Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>2th Left Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>1th Left Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>1th Right Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>2th Right Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>3th Right Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>4th Right Lane</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>5th Right Lane</b>
                </th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="/hall/row">
                <tr align="right">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./seat">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <tr>
                <xsl:value-of select="$STAtotal"/>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Seattotal"/>
            </tr>

            <!--Attempt_2
            <tr>
                <xsl:value-of select="$OSLeft"/>
            </tr>
            Attempt_2-->

            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="/hall/row/seat[@tag='0']">
                    <xsl:sort select="count(preceding-sibling::seat[@tag='0'])" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::seat)+1"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </body>

    <!--
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="inr" language="JScript">        
            function CLPosition(position, STAtotal)
            {
                // Make sure we have a valid number
                if (!isNaN(n))
                {   
                   
                }
                return "";
             }
</msxsl:script>
-->

</html>
```

What is the best approach to find this value?  I was thinking what would great is if I could get it and store it using xslt & xpath, but I don’t know if this is possible?  Perhaps I need to incorporate javascript into the stylesheet to get what I want?

Using my stylesheet as it is I believe I have got the value that I’m looking for but I have been unable to store it as a variable.  If you open my stylesheet you’ll see commented out code “<!--Attempt_2” at (line 11 thru 17 and 85 thru 87) where I tried to store it but I get the following error:

*"Error at char 7 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 83 column 49 of seatarrangement_testbed.xsl:   XPST0008  Variable OSLeft has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope) Warning at xsl:variable on line 14 column 53 of seatarrangement_testbed.xsl:   SXWN9001  A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation file contents written to stdin"*

Does anyone know of a way to get the variable approach to work?
If anyone has suggestions, recommendations, or a better approach let me know?

Thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get **as code**.

Comment: Good Idea Michael, I should have thought of that!  Here it is.  Peace,

Comment: Your output does not match the input. For example, there is no seat `+5_seat_C7` in row `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Could something like this work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/hall">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <th>-5</th>
            <th>-4</th>
            <th>-3</th>
            <th>-2</th>
            <th>-1</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> 
                </th>
                <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>                    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-cells">
    <xsl:param name="n" select="-5"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n &lt;5">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="seat[@tag=$n]"/> 
        </td>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added in view of clarifications:

If you don't know in advance how many seats can there be at most to the left and to the right of the "center" seat, and you cannot trust the minimum and maximum values of the `tag` attribute to tell you that, then this gets more complicated. Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/hall">
    <!-- get extrema -->
    <xsl:variable name="maxLeft">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:sort select="count(seat[@tag='0']/preceding-sibling::seat)" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(seat[@tag='0']/preceding-sibling::seat)"/> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="maxRight">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:sort select="count(seat[@tag='0']/following-sibling::seat)" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(seat[@tag='0']/following-sibling::seat)"/> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output --> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th/>
            <xsl:call-template name="generate-headings">
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="-$maxLeft"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$maxRight"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> 
                </th>
                <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells">
                    <xsl:with-param name="start" select="-$maxLeft"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$maxRight"/>
                </xsl:call-template>    
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>                    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-cells">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="end"/>
    <xsl:variable name="center" select="seat[@tag='0']" />
    <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $end">
        <td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$start &lt; 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center/preceding-sibling::seat[-$start]"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$start = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$center/following-sibling::seat[$start]"/> 
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-headings">
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:param name="end"/>
    <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $end">
        <th>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$start &lt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>Left:</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="-$start"/> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>Right:</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$start + 1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </th>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-headings">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<hall>
    <row name="a">
        <seat>-6_seat_A1</seat>
        <seat>-5_seat_A2</seat>
        <seat>-4_seat_A3</seat>
        <seat>-3_seat_A4</seat>
        <seat>-2_seat_A5</seat>
        <seat>-1_seat_A6</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_A7</seat>
        <seat>+2_seat_A8</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="b">
        <seat>-3_seat_B1</seat>
        <seat>-2_seat_B2</seat>
        <seat>-1_seat_B3</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_B4</seat>
        <seat>+2_seat_B5</seat>
        <seat>+3_seat_B6</seat>
    </row>
    <row name="c">
        <seat>-1_seat_C1</seat>
        <seat tag="0">+1_seat_C2</seat>
        <seat>+2_seat_C3</seat>
        <seat>+3_seat_C4</seat>
        <seat>+4_seat_C5</seat>
    </row>
</hall>
```

we will get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th/>
      <th>Left:6</th>
      <th>Left:5</th>
      <th>Left:4</th>
      <th>Left:3</th>
      <th>Left:2</th>
      <th>Left:1</th>
      <th>Right:1</th>
      <th>Right:2</th>
      <th>Right:3</th>
      <th>Right:4</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>-6_seat_A1</td>
      <td>-5_seat_A2</td>
      <td>-4_seat_A3</td>
      <td>-3_seat_A4</td>
      <td>-2_seat_A5</td>
      <td>-1_seat_A6</td>
      <td>+1_seat_A7</td>
      <td>+2_seat_A8</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>b</th>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td>-3_seat_B1</td>
      <td>-2_seat_B2</td>
      <td>-1_seat_B3</td>
      <td>+1_seat_B4</td>
      <td>+2_seat_B5</td>
      <td>+3_seat_B6</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>c</th>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td/>
      <td>-1_seat_C1</td>
      <td>+1_seat_C2</td>
      <td>+2_seat_C3</td>
      <td>+3_seat_C4</td>
      <td>+4_seat_C5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which renders as:

[image]

Comment: Michael the only issue I see that I should have made clear in the description is that the number of seats in a row will vary and the number of seats either side of Center will vary.

Comment: I have updated my description to clarify.

Comment: @Grot Why is this an issue with my code?

Comment: Am I mistaken or aren't you setting the start value of param 'n' to '-5' and that value will vary per source xml file.  Yeah the code that I provided as "desired result" doesn't reflect that.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your point. Isn't the number of columns reserved for seats fixed at 10 (5 on the left side and 5 on the right side)? I see this hardcoded in your attempt, so that's where I took it from.

Comment: The number of the columns can vary from 1 to ~12 to the 'left' of Center and 1 to ~12 the 'right' of Center.  This will vary per source xml.  That was why I was looking into some means of finding what I would call an 'offset' value so could use that as a limit for starting the number of columns.  Which is essentially what you named "param 'n'".

Comment: Would it be correct to use the min and max values of the `tag` attribute to determine the structure of the table?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I Really Appreciate the time you are pointing into helping me out.  The example data that I'm using is a simplified version of what I have to deal with and I don't think I can trust that the values of the 'tag' attribute will be consistent and useful as what I have shown here.  Is there a way I can count the number of 'seat' siblings up to the one with the "tag=0" for each 'row' and then find the largest of these values and then use that for your "param 'n'" value?  Either by using XPath/XSLT and or Javascript?

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that you still need to generate a fixed number of cells for each row (and populate only some of them). So the first thing you need to find out is how many cells can there be at most to the left of the "center" and how many to the right. If you cannot trust the min and max values of the` tag` attribute for this, then this is going to be challenging.

Comment: See if the added variation works for you.